# Getting Error as "Regex: syntax error in subpattern name (missing terminator)." in SPLUNK

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have been extracting fields in Splunk and this looks to be working fine for all headers but for the header l-s-m, I am getting the error as  "syntax error in subpattern name (missing terminator)."

I have done similar for other headers and all works but this is the only header with "hypen" sign that is giving this error, I have tried multiple times but this is not helping.

Headers:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json,application/problem json
l-m-n: txxxmnoltr 
Accept-Encoinding:gzip
```

Regex I am trying is `"rex field=u "l-m-n: (?<l-m-n>.*)"` in SPLUNK. Could you please guide me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rex` cannot extract into a field name with hyphens. However, you can solve this with `rename`

```
| rex field=u "l-m-n: (?<lmn>.*)" | rename lmn AS "l-m-n"
```

In general, I would avoid the use of hyphens in a field name, as it can be mistaken for a minus. If you want to use the field `l-m-n`, you will need to quote it everywhere, like `'l-m-n'` . **I would strongly suggest you stick with using the field name `lmn`.**

Try running the following to see what I mean

```
| makeresults | eval l-m-n=10 | eval l=1 | eval m=1 | eval n=1 | eval result_noquote=l-m-n | eval result_quoted='l-m-n'
```